# Collapse div when I click off element

Tags: javascript

I've made a collapsible menu with Vanilla JS which works fine, but I'd like for the menu to collapse when you click off it. I thought adding an event listener to the window would work, but I must have done something wrong.

```
const pageTitleDrop = document.getElementById('page-title');
const dropMenu = document.getElementById('dropdown');

pageTitleDrop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    dropMenu.classList.toggle('collapsed');
})

window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target !== dropMenu) {
        if (dropMenu.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
            return;
        } else {
            dropMenu.classList.toggle('collapsed');
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`e.target` can be the `dropMenu` but it could also be any child element of that container instead. You need to check ancestors of `e.target` for the dropdown. Thankfully, this is easy:

```
if( !e.target.closest("#dropdown")) {
    dropMenu.classList.add("collapsed");
}
```

Note that I've also simplified your code. Rather than "if the class is set, do nothing, else toggle the class", it's now just "add the class" -- if it's already there, nothing happens.